# How to edit an icon in Visual Studio

Tags: icons, visual-studio, image-editing

In Visual Studio 6 one could edit .ico files.

Today I've tried to do the same in Visual Studio 2019, but with no luck.
Is this feature removed or am I missing something?

Are there any replacements as simple as VS6?

I've tried GIMP - but it's too complex for a beginner.
*(It also doesn't allow to edit separate images for different dimensions inside of an .ico file;

at least I didn't understand how to do it).*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933304/how-to-create-an-icon-for-visual-studio-with-just-mspaint-and-visual-studio

Comment: I just dragged an icon into Visual Studio 2019 and the editor opened up with no problem.

Comment: @harrymc Had you been actually able to edit it? For me, all the editing controls are disabled. I can't do anything with the opened icon.

Comment: Yes, I was able to color it. Perhaps some missing option during the installation? Note that the VS icon editor is very primitive and there are much better free alternatives, for example [Greenfish](http://greenfishsoftware.org/) and its [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/greenfish-icon-editor-pro/?license=free&platform=windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an icon with just (Microsoft) Paint 3D / Paint and Visual Studio works just fine.
Here's how you should proceed to get it to work.

**In Visual Studio**

- Open `Resources.resx` from Solution Explorer *(it's in the Properties folder)*
  [image: Open Resources.resx]
- Choose `Icons` from DropDown Menu on the left [Ctrl+3]
  [image: Choose Icons]
- Choose `Add New Icon` from the DropDown Menu `Add Resource`
  [image: Choose Add New Icon]
- Enter a name for the Icon Resource file
- Right click on all the icons in the left panel - one at a time - and choose `Delete Image Type`
  *(Note: Do not choose Delete)*
  *(Note: The last icon cannot be deleted - Leave it for now)*
  [image: Choose Delete Image Type]

**In Paint 3D / Paint** *(or an image program of your choise)*

- Create/Open the image you would like to use *(it could be a screenshot of your program)*
- Resize the image to 256x256 pixels
  [image: Resize the image to 256x256 pixels]
- Select the full image [Ctrl+A] and then copy the image [Ctrl+C]

**In Visual Studio**

- Right click in the left panel (the icon panel) and choose `New Image Type...` [Ins]
  [image: Choose New Image Type...]
- Choose Target Image Type `256x256, 24 bit`
- *(Select the New Target Image Type and)* Paste [Ctrl+V] the image *(just copied)*

**In Paint 3D / Paint and in Visual Studio**

- Repeat the above "image copy" *(Paint 3D / Paint)* and "target paste" *(Visual Studio)* process for the 24 bit icon sizes `128x128`, `64x64`, `32x32` and `16x16` (and/or the ones you like to support)
- *Don't forget to delete the last icon you previously couldn't delete*
  [image: Delete the last icon you previously couldn't delete]

**In Visual Studio**

- Save the icon file (.ico) by right clicking on or closing its tab
  [image: Save the icon file]

**A couple of hints on how to use the icon in Visual Studio**

- Add the icon to your forms
  [image: Add the icon to your forms]
- Add the icon to your manifest resource

  - Right click your project file in the Solution Explorer and choose `Properties`
  - Choose the `Application` section
  - Under `Resources` - `Icon and manifest` click on `Browse` and select the icon file you just created.
    [image: Add the icon to Icon and manifest]

(Tested with Visual Studio 2017, 2019 & 2022).